# Rename a file listed on C# windows form listBox

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I am working on a Windows Form that should do the following:

1. Browse files on local drive
2. Allow the user to select files
3. List the selected files in a listBox
4. Allow the user to input a new file name and, when they click the rename button, it renames the selected file in the `ListBox`.

I am not able to do step 4 as the new text is changed in the listBox but the actual file name is still the same in folder. How can I do that? I have listed below the Form.cs

Thank you.

```
public partial class everSupportForm : Form
{
    private void buttonSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.Stream myStream;
        var myDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        myDialog.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        myDialog.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        //  + "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|" //If you want to add filters for browsing only images.
        myDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
        myDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        myDialog.Multiselect = true;
        myDialog.Title = "Please Select File(s) to Rename";

        if (myDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        {
            foreach (var file in myDialog.FileNames)
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((myStream = myDialog.OpenFile()) != null)
                    {
                        using (myStream)
                        {    
                            outputListBox.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Could not load File specifying the causes 
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot display the File");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => Application.Exit();

    // Removes a selected item
    private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (outputListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            outputListBox.Items.RemoveAt(outputListBox.SelectedIndex);
    }

    // Clears the listed images ListBox
    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => outputListBox.Items.Clear();
    private void buttonRename_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (outputListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
             outputListBox.Items[outputListBox.SelectedIndex] = newNametextBox.Text;
        else MessageBox.Show("There is no Files in the Above list to be Selected", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look this thread [Replace Text in ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236956/c-sharp-replace-text-in-listbox)

Comment: Please only include relavent code. Empty methods, for example, are not the source of the problem, and they only bloat the question. Also, no need to have comments when the method ends, we can figure that out on our own 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a problem here.
You're adding the files names using `Path.GetFileName`, so you won't have the files paths anymore => you can't rename them.

**Solution 1 - Adding the paths to the listbox**

You simple remove the `Path.GetFileName` and in when the rename button is clicked, you use an `InputBox` to ask the user for the new file name:
*N.B: Add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, `InputBox`is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction` namespace.*

```
private void buttonRename_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (outputListBox.SelectedIndex >=0)
    {
        string fileToRename = outputListBox.Items[outputListBox.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        string newFileName = InputBox("Please enter the new file's name:", "Rename file", "Default value");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newFileName))
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileToRename);
            string newFilePath = fileToRename.Replace(fileName, newFileName);
            System.IO.File.Move(fileToRename, newFilePath);
            outputListBox.Items[outputListBox.SelectedIndex] = newFilePath;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is no Files in the Above list to be Selected", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

**Solution 2 -- Keep a seperate list containing the paths**

The concept is the same as the first solution, but instead of adding the file paths to your listbox, you add the file names but you keep a seperate list of paths that is synced with your listbox.
Meaning that, if you modify the listbox, modify the list of paths.

After that you can access the file paths using the listbox's `SelectedIndex` (since they are synced).

Comment: Haytam ... should I change outputListBox.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file));

With:
outputListBox.Items.Add(file);

Is that what you meant?, or I remove the whole entire line ?

Comment: when i built the code, i got the following error regarding the following line of your code;

 string fileToRename = outputListBox.Items.SelectedItem.ToString();

Error CS1061 'ListBox.ObjectCollection' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItem' and no extension method 'SelectedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'ListBox.ObjectCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Corrected it, can you try it now?

Comment: If I want to rename the selected files in the richtextbox by adding the new name in the message box , how can rename the files to be like wcm1.png, wcm2.png , wcm3.png .. as all of my files are .png images .... Good on you.